# JMeter Custom Java Client to Test Websocket Application

Tags: java, websocket, jmeter

I am trying to benchmark an application running in the Cloud with JMeter. The underlying protocol uses websockets, but there are some proprietary libraries that I need to use to make those calls. I looked at some websocket plugins for JMeter. But more than just testing I want to use the ability of JMeter to be able to make distributed load generation for my server. I would like to use my own client (written in Java) to make the actual request for the server. Is this some how possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are different implementations of WebSocket Client API, i.e. [Jetty Websocket API](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-server-api.html) or [Java API for WebSocket](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html)

Recently I've been investigating on how WebSockets can be tested using [JMeter Load Testing Cloud Solution](http://blazemeter.com/). Kindly see proof of concept details below. It's using [JavaSamplerClient](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html) API so extension being packaged as a .jar and put under JMeter Classpath will be available as Java Request Sampler.

First of all you'll need [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) – open source JSR-356 implementation. Tyrus requires Java 7 so make sure that you use Java SE 7 to build and execute the extension. The most convenient way of getting dependencies is using following [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>blazemeter-websocket</groupId>

<artifactId>blazemeter-websocket</artifactId>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

<dependency>

<groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>

<artifactId>javax.websocket-client-api</artifactId>

<version>1.0</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>

<artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>

<version>1.1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>

<artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly</artifactId>

<version>1.1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>javax.json</groupId>

<artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>

<version>1.0</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>

<artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>

<version>1.0.1</version>

</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Invokation of target “mvn dependency:copy-dependencies” will download all required jars into /target/dependency folder. However you may with to continue with build, package, etc. maven plugins.

Source code of the extension is follows:

```
package com.blazemeter;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;

import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

import org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager;

import org.apache.log.Logger;

import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager;

import javax.websocket.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URI;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@ClientEndpoint

public class BlazemeterWebsocketRequest extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

private static String ws_uri;

private static String ws_message;

private static String response_message;

private static CountDownLatch latch;

private static final Logger log = LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass();

@Override

public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {

Arguments params = new Arguments();

params.addArgument("URI", "ws://echo.websocket.org");

params.addArgument("Message", "Blazemeter rocks!");

return params;

}

@Override

public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {

ws_uri = context.getParameter("URI");

ws_message = context.getParameter("Message");

}

@Override

public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext javaSamplerContext) {

SampleResult rv = new SampleResult();

rv.sampleStart();

latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

try {

client.connectToServer(BlazemeterWebsocketRequest.class, new URI(ws_uri));

latch.await(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

} catch (Throwable e) {

throw new RuntimeException(e);

}

rv.setSuccessful(true);

rv.setResponseMessage(response_message);

rv.setResponseCode("200");

if (response_message != null) {

rv.setResponseData(response_message.getBytes());

}

rv.sampleEnd();

return rv;

}

@OnOpen

public void onOpen(Session session) {

log.info("Connected ... " + session.getId());

try {

session.getBasicRemote().sendText(ws_message);

} catch (IOException e) {

throw new RuntimeException(e);

}

}

@OnMessage

public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {

log.info("Received ... " + message + " on session " + session.getId());

response_message = message;

try {

session.close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.NORMAL_CLOSURE,""));

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

return response_message;

}

@OnClose

public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {

log.info(String.format("Session %s close because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));

}

}
```

Hope this helps,

D.

Comment: Thanks, looking into Java Sampler!