# How to generate multiple login user in jmeter for java sampler request

Tags: java, websocket, jmeter, load-testing

Iam doing load test for gaming application which uses both https and websocket protocol.

I had used web-socket plugin by peter for ws connectio, but unable capture and handle all response.

I have a web-socket client connection java code(own websocket implementation)... How to integrate with jmeter???

If java sampler is a way to do it...then how to pass multiple user login for java request sampler..

Comment: Anyhelp regarding this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to develop your own [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler you need to inherit your class from [AbstractJavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html) and implement `SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context);` function

[JavaSamplerContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html) in its turn provides [getJMeterVariables()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html#getJMeterVariables--) function which you can use for accessing JMeter Variables originating from i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: ok Thanks.Our server side websocket protocol uses jetty client libraries....we can use java sampler for this too right??It is better if you can share any examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703946/jmeter-custom-java-client-to-test-websocket-application..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703946/jmeter-custom-java-client-to-test-websocket-application.. In this post mentioned as  Tyrus – open source JSR-356 implementation... for our java websecoket server side connection we uses, org.java-websocket,org.projectlombok,org.glassfish.jersey.containers,org.glassfish.jersey.media,javax.servlet.jsp